# Поиск по DataGridView и вывод данных в ТекстБоксы для редактирования - C#

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, textbox

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Как бы всё работает, нажимаешь на любое значение в DataGridView, и оно автоматически появляется в TextBox'ах через DataBings, для дальнейшего редактирования. Но когда я нахожу в DataGridView значение через поиск, оно уже перестаёт отображатся в TextBox'ах. В чём моя ошибка ?

Вот кода поиска:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource;
        }
        else
        {
            var query = from o in serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.DataSource as List<Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas>
                        where o.Serijos_Nr == textBox1.Text.Trim() || o.Serijos_Nr.Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Pavadinimas.Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Pakuote == textBox1.Text || o.Serijos_dydis.Contains(textBox1.Text)
                        select o;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SVF_ProtokolaiEntities serija;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bntNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //New insert
        {
            try
            {
                tabControl1.Enabled = true;
                textBox15.Focus();
                Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas c = new Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas();
                serija.Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas.Add(c);
                serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.Add(c);
                serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.MoveLast();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //edit
        {
            tabControl1.Enabled = true;
            textBox15.Focus();

        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //cancel edit
        {
            tabControl1.Enabled = false;
            serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in serija.ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        entry.Reload();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //save
        {
            try
            {
                serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.EndEdit();
                serija.SaveChangesAsync();
                tabControl1.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //Form
        {
            tabControl1.Enabled = false;
            serija = new SVF_ProtokolaiEntities();
            serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.DataSource = serija.Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas.ToList();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) //del from grid
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Ar tikrai norite ištrinti ?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    serija.Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas.Remove(serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.Current as Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas);
                    serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) //search
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource;
                }
                else
                {
                    var query = from o in serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.DataSource as List<Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas>
                                where o.Serijos_Nr == textBox1.Text.Trim() || o.Serijos_Nr.Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Pavadinimas.Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Pakuote == textBox1.Text || o.Serijos_dydis.Contains(textBox1.Text)
                                select o;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Eksporto mygtukas
        {
            Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
            fr2.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

До поиска

[image: до поиска]

После поиска

[image: после поиска]

Находит, но не отображает.

Comment: Последняя строка назначает новый источник данных, из отфильтрованного запроса. А к текстбоксам, как я понимаю, остаётся привязан первоначальный источник.

Comment: Да правельно, а мне нужен результат из поиска, чтобы отображался в текстбоксах

Comment: Ok, продолжу фиксить код, не видя его. После назначения нового источника данных гриду, нужно и текстбоксам прибиндить этот источник (не забыв очистить старый). Либо вместо `List<T>` взять такую коллекцию, которая поддерживает фильтрацию, например, `DataTable`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: окончательного решения нет еще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
{
    string text = textBox1.Text.Trim();

    if (text == string.Empty)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource;

        textBoxNumber.DataBindings.Clear();
        textBoxNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource, "Serijos_Nr");
    }
    else
    {
        var query = (from o in serijospakavimoprotokolasBindingSource.DataSource as List<Serijos_pakavimo_protokolas>
                     where o.Serijos_Nr.Contains(text) || o.Pavadinimas.Contains(text) || o.Pakuote == text || o.Serijos_dydis.Contains(text)
                     select o).ToList();

        if (query.Any())
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = query;

            textBoxNumber.DataBindings.Clear();
            textBoxNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", query, "Serijos_Nr");
        }
    }
}
```

`textBoxNumber` - это тот текстбокс, к которому осуществлена привязка. Замените название на то, которое у вас.
`"Serijos_Nr"` - свойство, к которому привязан этот текстбокс. Тоже замените на правильное. Но, думаю, я угадал.

Логика элементарная: когда что-то найдено - привязываем датагрид и текстбокс к найденным данным. Когда ничего не найдено - возвращаем первоначальные привязки.

---

Советы по коду: дайте всем контролам говорящие именования. Что такое `textBox1`? Если он предназначен для поиска/фильтрации, то и назовите его `textBoxSearch` или `textBoxFilter`. И т. д.
Я ввёл дополнительную локальную переменную `text`, благодаря чему код сильно сократился. Применяйте подобную технику.
Вот такой код: `.DataSource as List<T>` громоздок и медлителен. Здесь лучше напрямую использовать тот список, который является изначальным источником данных.

Comment: У меня к одной строке из датагрид привязанно более 100 текстбоксов. Поиск происходит с тектбокс1

Comment: @Вадим - Мда... Ну, код привязки, сгенерированный дизайнером, скопировать и вынести в метод. И вызывать его. Если будет медленно - придётся отказаться от этого способа и использовать, например, `DataTable` - у него встроенная возможность фильтрации.

Comment: У меня к одной строке из датагрид привязанно более 100 текстбоксов. Поиск происходит с тектбокс1. Serijos_Nr textbox15. Логика такая, заполняется верхние текстбоксы 6штук сразу, а по ходу производства, нужно найти нужную серию и продолжать по мере возможности заполнять и сохранить.

Comment: Может есть у Вас какой нибудь другой вариант или пример для моей задачи, а может Вы как профисионал моглибы написать достойный пример ? Я вам с производства чаю вышлю :)

Comment: @Вадим - Сгенерировал 200 текстбоксов, прибиндил. Работает без тормозов. Просто придётся скопировать код привязки всех ваших текстбоксов.

Comment: А если не возметесь, спасибо и на этом, буду гооглить, то о чем Вы мне сказали :)

Comment: Но скорей всего я оставлю все как есть, в базу добавлю столбец с нумерацией, отсортирую по убыванию, и особо поиск не нужен будет. Спасибо огромное за старание. Вы добрый человек :)

Comment: Проблема решена. Всем спасибо. Поиск работает :)